# Can't find specified path for easygui

Tags: python, module, zip, easygui

I'm trying to install easygui for python 3.4.3 but when I put in

```
cd C:\Users\Blank\Downloads\easygui-0.97.4.zip\easygui-0.97.4
```

in the command prompt it says

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Comment: Welcome to the party! Did you unzip the downloaded file? Also, Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Be sure to include all relevant part. Here you should add : how you downloaded `easygui-0.97.4.zip`, and how you unzipped it. Without it others will have to guess and could do a wrong guess.

Answer (score 0):

As you forgot some steps in the description of how you tried to install `easygui`, I have to guess.

I assume :

- you downloaded the file `easygui-0.97.4.zip` from ... (no importance) and have it in `C:\Users\Blank\Downloads\`
- but you forgot to unzip it (or the unzip has gone to another directory).

But as `C:\Users\Blank\Downloads\easygui-0.97.4.zip` is a zip file, Windows Explorer can show the content of the zip, but you cannot `cd` to it.

So you should explode the zip (*), that normally creates a new directory `C:\Users\Blank\Downloads\easygui-0.97.4` and then you should successfully be able to do :

```
cd C:\Users\Blank\Downloads\easygui-0.97.4
```

(*) Windows Explorer normally can do it, but you can also use [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for that